# React-Leaflet - Wait until WMSLayer has finished loading to redraw

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, wms, react-leaflet

I have a WMSLayer which takes a string of comma-separated layer names to make a call to fetch tiles.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { WMSTileLayer } from "react-leaflet";

class WMSLayers extends Component {
  render = () => (
    <WMSTileLayer
      format="image/png"
      layers={this.props.layers}
      url="https://ws.topogrids.de/geoserver/ows"
    />
  );
}
```

This component begins network requests when the `layers` prop changes. This means as soon as a new `layers` prop is passed, the current WMSLayer is erased, and new tiles begin to draw as they are received. This of course makes total sense.

What I would like to do is somehow retain the old component until the new tiles are fetched, and then render the new tiles all at once. This way, if I simply turn one more layer on, the current layers do not disappear.

I realize I can accomplish this by creating a separate WMSTileLayer for each layer, but this leads to many API calls per zoom/pan if multiple layers are switched on.

The layer does provide an `onLoad` event that gets fired when the tiles are done loading, but I don't know how to keep the old layers drawn until this is done, if it's even possible.

Advice would be greatly appreciated!

Also, this is not a duplicate of [How to keep old tiles until each new tile is loaded when redrawing a layer in Leaflet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25139505/how-to-keep-old-tiles-until-each-new-tile-is-loaded-when-redrawing-a-layer-in-le) - that question is about using multiple layers with one map, but this question is about using one layer with a map (I realize the WMSTileLayer `layers` prop name might make this seem confusing)

Comment: hey, if you got solution for this can you please share ?